# Fantasy drama/romance manga with a female lead whose mother and new stepfather die in a carriage accident

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I’m looking for the manga I read before but can’t remember the name mostly in color. The female lead (FL) joins a aristocratic family with a son(step brother) and new stepfather  (I think he had black hair). Her mother had been married multiple times and all of the husbands died. Her mother and new stepfather then die in a carriage accident and she is left with the son. He is somewhat obsessed with her and she is just trying to leave (he doesn’t want her to). The FL also had magic abilities ( I think she had sliver hair) she had a more reserved personality. Become one more “romantic” as they get older.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is ***[Why Ophelia Couldn't Leave](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nh8x68q/why-ophelia-couldn-t-leave)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> **When her mother remarries into the Arpad dukedom, Ophelia finds herself uprooted into the Arpad nobility. However, due to a tragic carriage accident, Ophelia's mother and stepfather suddenly lose their lives. Alexander, her stepbrother, urges her to stay in the Arpad household for the next three years.** One day, Ophelia hears devastating news from an investigator that changes everything. "The deaths of the Duke and Duchess of Arpad that took place this very day, three years ago... were not accidental deaths, but murders."

As noted in the synopsis above, the female lead's mother remarries a duke, but then the mother and stepfather are both killed in a carriage accident, leaving the female lead, Ophelia, and her younger stepbrother, Alexander, as orphans. Afterwards, she wants to leave, but he asks her not to, as he's lonely.

Ophelia has silver hair, while her stepfather and Alexander both have black hair. Ophelia's biological father and two previous stepfathers had also died, and Ophelia is later revealed to possess magical powers.

[image] [image]